# Abstract method implementation (if unused)

Tags: java

For instance, I have an abstract class implemented like this:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
   public abstract void makeNoise();
}
```

and I have a child class which is representing an animal that does not make any noise. Which is better?

```
public class Turtle extends Animal
{
   // properties and methods
   public void makeNoise()
   {
     //leave it empty
   }
}
```

or should i simply make it : `public abstract void makeNoise();` inside Turtle?

Comment: Unless `Turtle` is also supposed to be an abstract class, it cannot have any abstract methods.

Comment: Having `public abstract void makeNoise(); ` inside `Turtle` mean that you need to set the class `abstract` too. So you can't instantiate a `Turtle`. It doesn't seems correct...

Comment: It really depends on what you want to achieve. You also have the option that `Animal` by default does not have this method and it comes via an additional interface `CanMakeNoise`. Or you have an empty implementation, like you currently have, or you throw `UnsupportedOperationException` which means that `Turtle` can not make any noise. If you make it abstract than it means that you want `Turtle` to make noise but classes extending from `Turtle` need to implement it because you do not provide a *default implementation*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is better to move the `makeNoise()` method out of `Animal` as all the animals doesnot make noise. So create another interface `NoiseMaker` and add the the `makeNoise` method inside that.

```
public abstract class Animal {
  // animals methods
}

public interface NoiseMaker {
   void makeNoise();
}

public class Turtle extends Animal {
   // properties and methods which are applicable for turtle
}
```

And when you want an animal which makes noise like Lion you can extend `Animal` class and implement `NoiseMaker`, so that it has the behaviour of Animal as well as it makes noise.

```
public class Lion extends Animal implements NoiseMaker {
    public void makeNoise() {
        // implementation
    }

    // other properties and methods which are applicable for turtle
}
```

Comment: Good point about `makeNoise` being in the wrong place. I'd argue the thing providing `makeNoise` should be an interface (perhaps `NoiseMaker`).

Comment: Yes I have made it an interface

Comment: @Johny Thanks.. perhaps I would use interfaces since it's a behavior uncommon to all Animal subclasses

Answer (score 3):

What people often do: throw some sort of exception, like `UnsupportedOperationException` or something alike.

But: in the end your are fixing a **symptom** here.

The point is: extending a base class means that an object of the derived class **IS-A** object of the base class as well. And you are asking: how to violate the **public contract** of the base class.

And the answer is: you should **not** do that. Plain and simple.

Because if you start throwing exceptions here, all of a sudden, a caller that maybe has `List<Animal> animals` can't simply invoke `makeNoise()` on each object. The caller has instead to use `instanceof` (so that he can avoid calling `makeNoise()` on specific classes) - or try/catch is required.

So the real answer is: step back and improve your model. Make sure that all methods on the base class make sense for derived classes. If not - maybe introduce another layer, like `abstract class NoisyAnimal extends Animal`.

Comment: This is clearly a bad design that need to be fixed (unless this is too late...)

Answer (score 2):

This is the best use case to use `UnsupportedOperationException`

You have to implement because of the abstract design. So just implement the method and throw `UnsupportedOperationException` exception.

Keep it Animal, cause most of the Animal's make sound :) If you move it to Turtle, all the subclasses again have to have their own voice method.

Comment: See the end of the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> or should i simply make it : `public abstract void makeNoise();` inside `Turtle`?

If you do, `Turtle` is abstract. So the question isn't which is better, the question is, do you want to be able to instantiate `Turtle` or not?

If you do, you have to implement the method.

If you are okay with it being abstract, then declare it abstract and don't list the method at all:

```
public abstract class Turtle extends Animal {
}
```

Comment: So the question is who extend Turtle ? And if you leave it as abstract how to instantiate it ?

Comment: It's turtles all the way down

Answer (score 1):

You might want to distinguish between Animals making noises or not. Something a long the lines of

```
public abstract class Animals {}
public abstract class AnimalsNoisy extends Animals { abstract void makeNoise(); }
```

You would then use `Turtle extends Animals`. The advantage of this structure is if you have a List of Animals you don't need to worry if they implemented the `makeNoise` method or not e.g.

```
for(AnimalsNoisy animal: ListAnimalsNoisy) { animal.makeNoise();}
```

Comment: @AxelH Fixed it for you

Answer (score 0):

You may write like this,is this what you want?

```
public interface NoiseInterface {
    void makingNoise();
    void makingNoNoise();
}

public class Animal implements NoiseInterface{

    @Override
    public void makingNoise() {
        System.out.println("noising");
    }

    @Override
    public void makingNoNoise() {
        System.out.println("slient");
    }
}

public class Turtle extends Animal{

    @Override
    public void makingNoNoise() {
        System.out.println("turtle");
        super.makingNoNoise();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a good example to learn how to make your code loosely coupled.
By loosely coupled I mean, if you decide to change or modify your code you will not touch your previous code. Sometimes it is referred as OPEN-CLOSE principle.
For this first you have to identify what part of your code is frequently changing.
Here the method **makingNoise()** will have different implementation based on your class.

This design can be achieved in following steps.

> 1) Make an interface which will have implementation for makeNoise()
>   method.

```
public interface NoiseInterface {
   public void speak();
}
```

> 2) Create concrete implementation for NoiseInterface

eg: For Fox

```
public class FoxSound implements NoiseInterface {

  @Override
  public void speak()
   {
      //What does the fox say ?
      Sysout("chin chin chin tin tin tin");
   }
}
```

> 3: Provide the Noise Interface in Animal Class

```
public abstract class Animal
{
   public NoiseInterface noiseMaker;

   public abstract void makeNoise();

}
```

> 4: Just provide the Type of NoiseInterface of your choice in Fox Class

```
public class Fox extends Animal
{
   public Fox()
   {
     noiseMaker = new FoxSound();
   }
   public void makeNoise()
   {
     noiseMaker.speak();
   }
}
```

Now Amazing thing about this design is you will never have to worry about the implemetation. I will explain you how.

> You will just call

```
Animal me = new Fox();
fox.makeNoise();
```

Now in future you want to mute the Fox. 
You will create a new Interface Mute

```
public class Mute implements NoiseInterface {

  @Override
  public void speak()
   {
      Sysout("No sound");
   }
}
```

Just change the NoiseBehavior in Fox class constructor

```
noiseMaker = new Mute();
```

You can find more on **OPEN-CLOSE** Principle [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)